# Making a tricky mysql virtual column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, virtual-column

am trying to use mysql virtual columns feature to achieve a search mechanism where i have booking numbers may be a real integer like 101 or an alpha numeric as A101 , B101 etc.

So i do need to make a search mechanism where the use will input 101 and i will fetch all bookings with 101 which certainly one booking but also i will fetch all those bookings with characters like A101 , B101 i hope you got the point.

i used virtual columns with json and they were very effective like the following.

```
            DB::statement('ALTER TABLE finances ADD meta_type BIGINT AS (JSON_UNQUOTE(meta->"$.type"))');
```

and here am extracting the json value and assign it to my new virtual column

now i need to make the same step but with another logic

```
  DB::statement('ALTER TABLE bookings ADD number_vc  BIGINT AS ( convert number column which is alpha numeric to integer only  )');
```

i want to get rid of all char in the number column value strip it all and leave only the integer to be assigned to my number_vc new column , so when my migration executed successfully i will end up with the following

| id | number | number_vc (the new virtual column) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 101 |
| 2 | A101 | 101 |
| 3 | B101 | 101 |

So am missing the As ( convert in my statement ) so any help would be appreciated !

Comment: If the format is always the same (1 character followed by the number you want), then you could use the sql `substring()` function

Comment: am afraid it may be one character or two like A101 , B101 .... AA101 , AB101 etc

Comment: @RaymondNijland you know what , it actually did the trick. thanks can u post it as an answer so that i can accept it. thank you so much

Comment: @RaymondNijland hey man just one note the way you suggested works great with all numbers except numbers that ends with 0 or 00 so if the number is A10 it will be stored as 1 if it was A100 it will also stored as 1 if it was A2500 it will be stored as 25 .... and so on so what do you suggest !!!

Comment: the issue is in this part REVERSE(REVERSE("A100") << 0)

Comment: forget the `REVERSE(REVERSE("A100") << 0)`  that indeed does not work with 0 at the end i forgot about that case  does this even more tricky SQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c998e1/12 help you out, it seams to be working fine with test data

Comment: @RaymondNijland again you are the savior :-D do you know how can i perform this inside a laravel migration to make my virtual column as i can see on sqlfiddle a large select statement with many unions !!

Comment: i think i would make a view out of it instead of a virtual column it makes it bit more sense and query the view instead in your application where would need that column information ..it also might make it more easy to use with laravel migration but i am not sure of it as i never used laravel migration

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok man i really appreciate you help so thank you so much hope you're having a great day